# How to fade in/out five css background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, background, rotation

I am currently using this and it rotates to the next image and repeats 1-5

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    var images = [ "redesign/slides/Big_1.jpg", "redesign/slides/Big_2.jpg", "redesign/slides/Big_3.jpg", "redesign/slides/Big_4.jpg", "redesign/slides/Big_5.jpg"  ];
    var currentImage = 0;

    function changeBackground() {
        $( '#body_container' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ')' } );
        if ( currentImage >= images.length - 1 ) {
            currentImage -= images.length;
        }
    }
    setInterval( changeBackground, 2000 );  
});
```

But how do I get the images to fade in/out to the next image?

You can see the full home page in action here:  http://www.arcolacovenant.org/redesign_index

Also, how can I make each image linkable to different pages when the image is displayed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a slider, use a slider. There are literally thousands. [nivo](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

If you really want to make one yourself, just to learn how, there are even thousands of tutorials. There are so many articles on how to make sliders, there are [round-up articles on all the articles](http://naldzgraphics.net/tutorials/25-must-learn-slider-tutorials-with-jquery/).

Comment: i second..not worthwhile to reinvent this one.